# Sheets Exports Time Incorrectly to Calendar Event Description Dec 1899

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I bake/sell cookies. I added code to create calendar events from my Sheet that's updated when someone submits my Form for a cookie order.
All is working perfectly except in the calendar event description.

I want the event to show as an all day event (it does) and just have the pickup time listed in the description. But for some reason it's not only importing the incorrect time, it's also including December 30, 1899...
Here's my code, a screenshot of my Sheet, and a screenshot of the calendar event.
Any suggestions?

```
    //Function to create calendar event//
    function scheduleCookies() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var calendarId = 'kinglmandi@gmail.com';
      var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
      var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
      var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("C2:I"+lr+"").getValues();
     
      
      for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
        var order = signups[x];
        var title = order[0];
        var date = order[6];
        var pickupTime = order[5];
        var options = order[4];
        var quantity = order[1];
        var dough = order[2];
        var icing = order[3];
        var events = eventCal.getEventsForDay(date);
        if (events.length == 0 || events.filter(function(e) {return e.getTitle() == title}).length == 0) {
          eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description: pickupTime + " - " + options + " - " + quantity + " - " + dough + " dough " + icing + " icing "});
        }
      
      }
    }
```

[image: Sheets screen shot]

[image: Event screen shot]